# PHP|MySql - cannot insert text contains apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

[I am using phpmyadmin]

I want to insert the long texts which are a large description of a city or region. 
It contains apostrophe and comma, but when inserted, comma is not a problem but the apostrophe are.

For eg.

> **'** Taunggyi's the administrative capital for the whole of Shan State. Perched on top of a mountain, it's also a busy trading post,
>   and the...**'**,

It will an input from the user (type-in) to the text area on my website. 
So it cannot define statically like other examples I found.

Current one 
`//php $name=$_REQUEST["name"]; //
 //in insert query =>  '.$name.',`

Have tried like below too, but not working.

```
'".$name."',
```

Any good ideas, please! Your help is most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the quote with a backslash. Like 'sumit\'s'.

Here is an example function, using mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

In your case, it should be `mysql_real_escape_string($name)`

Comment: Please don't assume that OP is using **dangerous** and **unsafe** `mysql_*` functions, *always ask.*

Comment: You are not wrong. But also not to presume that the user is definitely using mysqli extension and not mysql. @RajdeepPaul

Comment: That's why I said, *always ask* what driver OP is using. MySQLi? PDO? Who knows.

Comment: thank you. my case worked with this "mysql_real_escape_string($name)" @sumitbadaya

Comment: @Nai glad that it helped

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping special characters? Below should be helpful:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
```

I created a function called post() and each time I need something from `$_POST` I simple call `post('item_name');` the function than perform escaping and returns safe string ... There are numerous questions and answers to your question including this one: [Properly Escaping with MySQLI | query over prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311686/properly-escaping-with-mysqli-query-over-prepared-statements)

Comment: In the procedural way, [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function takes two arguments, first is the connection handler and second is the string to escape.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Good catch - I've updated my answer + upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [even escaping string won't prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218691/mysql-real-escape-string-solve-sql-injection-definitely). +1 for the link btw.